# Override a route in Spree ecommerce 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'd like to redirect `/cart` to my homepage in Spree 2.0. I tried to use:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do  
   get '/cart' => redirect("/")
end
```

in my route.rb but rails keep complaining I'm duplicating my route. Obvisouly that's not the right method. How should I do? (prepend or append didn't work either).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any way of overriding routes, but this is how I ended up doing this in my application (in **app/spree/controllers/orders_controller_decorator.rb**):

```
module Spree
  OrdersController.class_eval do
    before_filter :redirect_to_root, only: [:cart]

    private
      def redirect_to_root
        redirect_to root_path
      end
  end
end
```

I would still be interested to know if somebody has done with overriding routes. :)

Comment: Great question, I would like to know as well.